# A word that means to "Reproportionalise"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Adjusting the measurement interval required us to readjust the
>   weights of all the measurements so that the overall magnitude of the result 
>   would remain constant.

`function reproportionalise_weights(...) {...}`

Unfortunately "reproportionalise" is not in the dictionary.

Is there any word in English that can convey the meaning of "adjust something so it is once again in proportion with something else"?

I don't want to use "adjust" since it does not convey enough context.

Thanks

Comment: _Not in the dictionary_? Using 'the dictionary' in place of say 'Lexico, AHD, Collins, M-W, ...' is imprecise. I've found 'reproportion' in one online dictionary (Dictionary.com) and am prepared to wager that OED (which I haven't got access to) will list it.

Comment: And you already have *weighting*. That is a proper term for this. You had to [reweight](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C34&q=reweighting+sample&btnG=) the measurements.

Comment: If the adjustment was linear, I'd recommend *rescale* to imply they were all adjusted proportionately. "Adjusting the measurement interval required us to rescale the weighting factors of all the measurements so that the overall magnitude of the result would remain constant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm... I believe I checked "reproportionalise". Apologies. I have edited the question.

Comment: So why isn't 'reproportion' a strong candidate? It's given as a transitive verb. // 'In the dictionary' is still poor. If any one dictionary can legitimately be referred to as '_the_ dictionary', it has to be OED. Have you checked there (and one mustn't confuse it with Lexico)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because questions about what to name software functions and methods are specifically off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like *normalising*, which is a technical term **in [statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))** and describes what you are talking about there.

Comment: I think "normalising" would imply the existence of an "innate" normal state (for the object or for the group containing the object), whereas I need to describe proportionality with something else (whether the object/containing group is normal or not is of no consequence).

Comment: No, normalising just means applying a statistical procedure, nothing to do with any inherent state. It adjusts the data to have a given mean and standard deviation.

Comment: "bring or return to a normal or standard condition or state" - Oxford, although I acknowledge you meant "in statistics". Just backing up my view.

Comment: I expressly stated that I was referring to it as a technical term. That is a completely different usage from the normal dictionary meaning.

Comment: @Hassaan, since you're talking about measurements, using the technical meaning is appropriate. In engineering we also talk about *normalizing* a measurement to exactly what your example says: re-scaling a measurement to keep the magnitude of the sum of a set of measurements constant (i.e., in a situation with no statistics involved)